# Flutter Navigator.pop Invalid Constant Value Error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I was writing a simple code but it gives an error.

this my code:

[image]

please help me guys :(

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove const keyword before Scaffold**

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text("Go Back!"),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text Button itself is designed correctly. I think the error might be that you gave Scaffold a const. Remove Const before Scaffold .